# How to display minutes and seconds using vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, time

My console.log shows the minutes and seconds, but I can’t bring them in {{time}}，
How to bring the value into the div display？

```
<div>{{time}}</div>

<script>
    export default {

    data() {
        return {
            time: 900
          }
        },

    methods: {
     countdown() {
       this.time --;
       let minuteTime = parseInt(this.time / 60)
       let minuteTime = parseInt(this.time % 60)
       this.time = minuteTime + 'minute' + minuteTime + 'second'
       if(this.time === 0){
        clearInterval(this.timer)
       }
     }
    },

    mounted(){
     this.timer = setInterval(this.countdown, 1000)
    },

    beforeDestroy(){
        clearInterval(this.timer)
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you are using the `time` to do calculation - `time--` and assign string 'minute' and 'second' to it which will yield NaN result and the setInterval will never end as the time will never be 0. You need to have another variable for displaying the text. Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-goldwasser-495d8?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: The answer from Mic Fung would work. Also, why would you name the variables the same? It's a bit confusing to read. Just a tip. Good luck.